# How to get text from EditText within ListView with multiple Views?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-edittext

I have a ListView that contains two TextViews and one EditText in each row. I have searched and searched and cannot figure out how to get the text that the user enters into the EditText. My most recent attempt implements a TextWatcher.

```
public void addIngredientToMeal(String ingredientName) {

    ingredient_list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ingredients_in_meal_listView);

    int numberOfIngredients = ingredient_list.getChildCount();

    ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter();
    adapter.name_array = new String[numberOfIngredients+1];

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfIngredients; i++)
        adapter.name_array[i] = (String) ingredient_list.getItemAtPosition(i);

    adapter.name_array[numberOfIngredients] = ingredientName;
    ingredient_list.setItemsCanFocus(true);
    ingredient_list.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    public String[] name_array, qty_array;

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(name_array != null && name_array.length != 0){
            return name_array.length;    
        }
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return name_array[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            //ViewHolder holder = null;

            final ViewHolder holder;
                if (convertView == null) {

                    holder = new ViewHolder();
                    LayoutInflater inflater = NewMeal.this.getLayoutInflater();
                    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ingredients_in_meal_layout, null);
                    holder.textView1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ingredient_name_in_new_meal_textView);
                    holder.editText1 = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ingredient_qty_in_new_meal_editText);
                    holder.textView2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ingredient_unit_in_new_meal_textView);

                    convertView.setTag(holder);

                } else {

                    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                }

                holder.ref = position;
                holder.textView1.setText(name_array[position]);
                holder.textView2.setText(databaseAdapter.dbQuery(name_array[position]));
                holder.editText1.setText(qty_array[position]);
                holder.editText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                        @Override
                        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            }

                        @Override
                        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                    int arg3) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                                qty_array[holder.ref] = arg0.toString();

                        }
                });
            return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView textView1, textView2;
        EditText editText1;
        int ref;
    }


}
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For those who may have a similar issue, I solved the problem I was having.

The problem:
Need to get values entered in multiple editTexts that are contained within a listView. Using listviewname.getItemAtPosition(integer) only gets the value of the first editText. Moreover, I had multiple views contained in each row of the listview, so getItemAtPosition only returned the value of the first view in the first row of the listView.

The solution:

- Define a listView object that identifies the listview that we care
  about
- Define a View object that can get the listview
- Define whatever field(s) you are trying to get from the listview (EditTexts, TextViews Etc.)
- Get the number of rows that the listview currently contains
- Set the view object using listviewname.getChildAt(position)
- Assign the field (say, an editText) using something like (EditText) viewObject.findViewById(R.id.edittextid)
- Get the value from the field using editTextObject.getText().toString()

Here's some sample code that could be implemented on a button press:

```
ListView lvName = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview1);
View v;
EditText et;

int listLength = lv.getChildCount();
String[] valueOfEditText = new String(listLength);
for (int i = 0; i < listLength; i++)
{
    v = lvName.getChildAt(i);
    et = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
    valueOfEditText[i] = et.getText().toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

getFocusedChild(position) it will return a View, or findFocus()

```
View row = ingredient_list.getFocusedChild();
EditText et =  (EditText)row.findViewById(R.id.ingredient_qty_in_new_meal_editText);
```

Edit

Sorry i misunderstood create a gist will toast with the input

https://gist.github.com/imjarp/9313c687ccbe339d052f

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your code looks good but I have 2 concerns. 1. Can I get the text from a function outside IngredientAdapter? 2. someArray[] has a predefined size, but mine will be determined by how many entries a user makes. Is there a way to handle these?

Comment: Sorry about the late reply, about your concerns 1. Yes you can if you define you a separte Listener class and assign it , 2 You can add items to you adapter and then call adapter.notifydatasetchanged(), but to be honest i would use some DialogFragment to add the ingredients to your list , instead of using and edit text :) hope it help you

Comment: Thanks for helping so far. Let me be a little less vague about what I'm trying to do. I have a listview (with two textviews and one edittext per row) that initially has no children. The user is able to add items to this list using a spinner (which is working fine). Once the user has added as many rows as they need to the listview, they can type data into the editTexts that have appeared. Finally, they click a save button which needs to get the data from all textViews and editTexts in the listView.