# Is there any way to make a ArrayList of TextView from one TextView defined in xml?

Tags: java, android

I want to make an ArryList of TextView.

sector.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:gravity="center">

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/sectNameVew"
    android:layout_width="0sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="60"
    android:textSize="20sp"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Now i want to create an ArrayList like this:

```
ArrayList<TextView> arLst = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
   TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.sectorNamesView);
   tv.setText((i + 1) + "");
   arrLst.add(tv);
}
```

When i use the arLst, it shows that every TextView in arrLst has text "10".
But i want to store it as each TextView will have different text like "1", "2", "3", ... ... ... "10".
Even i want to dynamically add more item in that arrLst from user. So it can not be defined 10 TextView in xml text. Because number of items may increased.

How can i do that?
Thanks <3

Comment: If an answer helps you, please mark it as Accepted. It also gives you some reputation points :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to create the `TextView` programmatically and add it to the `LinearLayout` (the parent view).

First, you will want to assign an `id` to your `LinearLayout`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parentLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center">

</LinearLayout>
```

So, your code will look a little like this:

```java
LinearLayout parentLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parentLayout);

int num_textViews = 10; // number of textViews you might want in your ArrayList
ArrayList<TextView> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < num_textViews; i++) {
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText((i + 1) + "");
    // add any styling you wish

    arrayList.add(tv);
    parentLayout.addView(tv);
}
```

Comment: So i should not use any specific id of TextView. Thank you so much. You helped me lot <3

Comment: Nope, you want to create the `TextView` as you go

Comment: Sir, I have another question related to this otherwise i would post it. 
I have created a `ListView` from an `ArrayList` of type `ArrayList<EditText>` .
Now how can i get user input from that `AdapterView` of the `ListView` (or any other way) ?

I wrote a code like this:
`EditText soc =
                                (EditText) sectAdapter.getItem(position);
String amount = soc.getText(); `

But it is giving no string even i give inputs.

Thanks.

Comment: Alright, you're gonna want to check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31210934/5512292). Please use a `RecyclerView` instead of a `ListView`. It is much better

Comment: sir, thank you so much. 
Now It works completely fine.